# Display error message if no result found in search bar

Tags: angular, ionic3

I am stuck in search problem. If the user search for something and that is not present in list than it should display error message. But in my case, If I search "panadol" in my list than it will display the list which contains this word and will display the error message on the list which does not contain this word.

Searchbar.html:

```
<ion-searchbar (keyup)="searching()" placeholder="{{'search' | translate}}" [(ngModel)]="terms"></ion-searchbar>

<div *ngIf="terms == undefined || (terms.length > 1 && !((infectiousdiseasesList.DiseaseCategoryId == 4) && (infectiousdiseasesList.DiseaseName_En.toUpperCase().includes(terms.toUpperCase()) || infectiousdiseasesList.DiseaseName_Ar.includes(terms))) )">
{{'noItemsFound' | translate}}
</div>

<span *ngFor="let infectious of infectiousdiseasesList;let i = index">
  <ion-row
    *ngIf=" (infectious.DiseaseCategoryId == 4) && (infectious.DiseaseName_En.toLowerCase().includes(terms.toLowerCase()) || infectious.DiseaseName_Ar.includes(terms))"
    col-12>
    <!-- (infectious.DiseaseCategoryId == 4) && -->
    <ion-col col-6>
      <ion-item no-lines>
        <ion-label *ngIf="this.lang == 'en'">{{infectious.DiseaseName_En}}</ion-label>
        <ion-label *ngIf="this.lang == 'ar'">{{infectious.DiseaseName_Ar}}</ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="infectious.checked" (ionChange)="selected(infectious,i, $event)" color="danger">
        </ion-checkbox>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</span>
```

Searchbar.ts:

```
this.storage.get('infectiousDiseases').then(res => {
    for(let infectious of res){
      if(infectious.DiseaseCategory.Id==4){
        this.infectiousdiseasesList.push(infectious);
      }
    }
 });
```

[Now if you see the picture there is a list shown there. If I type "as" in the searchbar then the list containing "as" words will be shown and the list that does not contain the searched word will shown error message. In my case, I am getting error message and result too.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hM2u1.png)

Comment: In case of error put `infectiousdiseasesList = [];` and you're up to go.

Comment: @JacopoSciampi i have to show error. If i will remove the check from html page it will automatically show blank page which i don't want.

Comment: Your html is fine. The problem, I guess, is that when you get an error (like `as` gets no results) you correctly show the error message but the list is not being cleaned. That's why you have both the message and the items listed. So, in your ts code, when you catch that error, add that line I've posted above.

Comment: in my case the word which contains "as" is being displayed and the word which dose not contain "as" showing no item found message. I want if any word contain the "as" than error message should not be displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a opposite condition in the result display.

```
<div *ngIf="terms == undefined || (terms.length > 1 && !((infectiousdiseasesList.DiseaseCategoryId == 4) && (infectiousdiseasesList.DiseaseName_En.toUpperCase().includes(terms.toUpperCase()) || infectiousdiseasesList.DiseaseName_Ar.includes(terms))) )">
{{'noItemsFound' | translate}}
</div>
<div *ngIf="terms != undefined && ((infectiousdiseasesList.DiseaseCategoryId == 4) && (infectiousdiseasesList.DiseaseName_En.toUpperCase().includes(terms.toUpperCase()) && infectiousdiseasesList.DiseaseName_Ar.includes(terms))">
<span *ngFor="let infectious of infectiousdiseasesList;let i = index">
  <ion-row
    *ngIf=" (infectious.DiseaseCategoryId == 4) && (infectious.DiseaseName_En.toLowerCase().includes(terms.toLowerCase()) || infectious.DiseaseName_Ar.includes(terms))"
    col-12>
    <!-- (infectious.DiseaseCategoryId == 4) && -->
    <ion-col col-6>
      <ion-item no-lines>
        <ion-label *ngIf="this.lang == 'en'">{{infectious.DiseaseName_En}}</ion-label>
        <ion-label *ngIf="this.lang == 'ar'">{{infectious.DiseaseName_Ar}}</ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="infectious.checked" (ionChange)="selected(infectious,i, $event)" color="danger">
        </ion-checkbox>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</span>
```

or simple way:

```
<ion-searchbar (keyup)="searching()" placeholder="{{'search' | translate}}" [(ngModel)]="terms"></ion-searchbar>

    <div *ngIf="terms == undefined || (terms.length > 1 && !((infectiousdiseasesList.DiseaseCategoryId == 4) && (infectiousdiseasesList.DiseaseName_En.toUpperCase().includes(terms.toUpperCase()) || infectiousdiseasesList.DiseaseName_Ar.includes(terms))) )">
    {{'noItemsFound' | translate}}
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="terms != undefined && infectiousdiseasesList">
    <span *ngFor="let infectious of infectiousdiseasesList;let i = index">
      <ion-row
        *ngIf=" (infectious.DiseaseCategoryId == 4) && (infectious.DiseaseName_En.toLowerCase().includes(terms.toLowerCase()) || infectious.DiseaseName_Ar.includes(terms))"
        col-12>
        <!-- (infectious.DiseaseCategoryId == 4) && -->
        <ion-col col-6>
          <ion-item no-lines>
            <ion-label *ngIf="this.lang == 'en'">{{infectious.DiseaseName_En}}</ion-label>
            <ion-label *ngIf="this.lang == 'ar'">{{infectious.DiseaseName_Ar}}</ion-label>
            <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="infectious.checked" (ionChange)="selected(infectious,i, $event)" color="danger">
            </ion-checkbox>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </span>
</div>
```

and:

```
    this.storage.get('infectiousDiseases').then(res => {
      if(res){
         for(let infectious of res){
          if(infectious.DiseaseCategory.Id==4){
            this.infectiousdiseasesList.push(infectious);
          }
        }
      } else {
          this.infectiousdiseasesList = []; // [] or maybe null 
      }     
 });
```

Comment: same issue as I am getting earlier :(

Comment: can you post your project on stackblitz or some IDE online ? i can check what wrong

Comment: Sorry i am not allowed to post project. You can see the link given in my description to see the only case left to cover.